# I am looking for a central action solution for tph tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0, table-per-hierarchy

Net core project, I'm writing a ticket management service.

I applied the **TPH**(Table Per Hierarchy) method in the database.
I created a table called **TicketGeneral** as a main table.
The names of the **sub-entities** are as follows:
**TicketMobileType**
**TicketRequestType**.

I also have history (log) tables with exactly the same table structure.
I also created a History table using **TPH**. The name of the relevant main table is **TicketGeneralHistory** and its sub-entities are:
**TicketMobileTypeHistory**
and **TicketRequestTypeHistory**.

For each **CRUD** operation to be performed within the main tables, I want to record the History table with the **action** column. (its a string column for ["Insert","DELETE","UPDATE"])
Can I do this by setting up a single central structure instead of writing repetitive code for each entity separately?

*Notes: I can't use a trigger via database for this scenario*

Comment: Side note: Multiple tables is not TPH. TPH means single table with discriminator column. The term for multiple tables is TPT (Table Per Type).

Comment: You're right, actually that's what i wanted to mention, a single table with discriminator column.

Comment: Why don't you write the "repetitive code for each entity separately" and then see if there's anything you can refactor to simplify the implementation?